# user.update :last_search_at => Time.current Always Returns False

Tags: ruby-on-rails

When I call `test_function` , `puts user.update :last_search_at => Time.current` is always returning `false` although the third `puts` value is correct: `2016-06-10 20:40:33 UTC` . `user.save` never works and first `puts` always returns nothing.

```
def test_function
  puts user.last_search_at
  puts user.update :last_search_at => Time.current
  puts user.last_search_at
  user.save
end
```

I would appreciate hearing your thoughts. Thanks for reading!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main reason why the update may fail is because the record is invalid.

Print out the list of errors after the update

```
p user.update :last_search_at => Time.current
p user.error.full_messages
```

and make sure the record is valid.

Comment: Thanks for your fast reply! What a stupid mistake: `"Email can't be blank"` ... Anyway, I cannot set email as nullable: `rails generate migration change_column_null :users, :email, true; rake db:migrate;` . schema.rb never change. Any thoughts?

Comment: Solved! It was because of Devise. I used this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/27723647/488019